# Polymer paper-tab select first tab programmatically

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Our paper-tabs are generated dynamically, how can we select the first tab by default and also fire the change event so that the iron page content is visible.

```
<paper-tabs id="scrollableTabs" selected={{selected}} scrollable >
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[liveQueues]]" as="queue" >
    <paper-tab on-click="listLiveTokens" >[[queue.queueName]]</paper-tab>
  </template>
</paper-tabs>


 list: function() {

        this.loading=!this.loading;
        this.$.list.url = "http://apicall";
        var tmp = this.$.list.generateRequest();
        console.log(tmp)

    },
```

this script fetches the tab content from the api call

```
<iron-pages  selected="{{selected}}">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[liveQueues]]" as="queue" >
    <paper-material elevation="1">
        <iron-list items="[[queueTokens]]" as="token">
          <template>
            <div>
              <div class="item" tabindex="0">
                <span class="avatar" >[[token.tokenNumber]]</span>
                <a href$="{{_getDetailsLink(token.tokenId,token.tokenNumber,token.userName,token.statusType,token.userMobile,token.joinDate)}}">
                  <div class="pad">
                    <div class="primary">[[token.userName]]</div>
                    <div class="secondary">[[token.userMobile]]</div>
                    <div class="secondary dim">[[token.notes]]</div>
                      <div class="secondary dim">[[token.joinTime]]</div>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <iron-icon icon$="[[iconForItem(sminq)]]"></iron-icon>
              </div>
            </div>
          </template>
        </iron-list>
    </paper-material>
  </template>
</iron-pages>
```

Comment: Are they generated in a repeat template? Is there any way to know generation is finished? A code snippet would help.

Comment: @Maria they are generated in a repeat template, i have added code snippets

Answer (score 0):

An event will fire every time the dom-repeat changes. You could listen to changes and set selected to 0.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[liveQueues]]" as="queue" on-dom-change="setSelected">
```

In your prototype you define the function.

```
setSelected: function() {
   this.$.scrollableTabs.selected = 0;
}
```

Note that the function is called every time you update liveQueues and you may not want to reset the tabs every time.
The iron pages should update automatically, if you have data-binding to `selected`.

Comment: Hi @maria that was a really helpful, i just had another question the tab gets selected. I also select the iron page using another id like                                         

           this.$.scrollablePages.selected = 0;
But the iron-list that loads the list is not visible.

Comment: If you use data-binding it shouldn't be necessary to set selected in the pages. Have a look at [this simple plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K59phuCAbtLR10ltLp28?p=preview). Note that the plunker only works in Chrome, but if you host the example on your own machine it should work in other browsers, too. The populate buttons simulates data arriving asynchronously and adds the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that ready function is the way to initialize !

```
ready: function() {
  this.selected = 0;
}
```